# Param is missing or the value is empty.Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I try to make a multiupload pictures with carrierwave in my app.There is 2 class: `Downloader` and `Pictures`

`Downloader` has a two default field

```
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
```

and `downloaders_controller`

```
class DownloadersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @downloader = Downloader.new  
    @picture = @downloader.pictures.build
  end

  def create
    @downloader = Downloader.new(downloader_params)
    if @downloader.save
      params[:pictures]['image'].each do |img|
        @picture = @downloader.pictures.create!(image: img, downloader_id: @downloader.id)
      end
      redirect_to new_downloader_path
    end
  end

  private
  def downloader_params
    params.require(:downloader).permit(pictures_attributes: [ :image ])
  end
end
```

`pictures` table

```
  create_table "pictures", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "image"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "downloader_id"
  end
```

view `new`

```
= form_for @downloader, multiple: true do |f|
  = f.fields_for :pictures do |p|
    = p.file_field :image, multiple: true, name: "pictures[image][]"
  = f.submit
```

and when I create a new `downloader` object, shell show me an error

```
param is missing or the value is empty: downloader
```

how fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
p.file_field :image, multiple: true, name: "downloader[pictures[image][]]"
```

But as a rule of thumb, you should avoid overriding rails conventions and just play with it.

Also, by overriding the input name like this, your strong parameter definition might not work with `pictures_attributes` anymore.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but sorry - I don't understand what do you mean.Could you detail about it?

Comment: Sure. By specifying a name like this `name: "pictures[image][]"` you override rails defaults. By default rails would wrap your form attributes into a `downloader` key but since you manually set the image field name, you break the default and it starts not working as expected. Just avoid messing with rails defaults unless you know and understand what you are doing. No offense of course.